# catching all but specific exception in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception

I have a code base with code like the following:

```
try:
    do_stuff()
except:
    print "yes, it's catching EVERYTHING"
```

Unfortunately, I don't have a quick enough way of knowing which types of exceptions can come, and am unable to let the system collapse upon encountering one.

This makes debugging hell.

I would like to make it easier upon myself by letting specific exceptions slip by - things like syntax errors, and others.

Is that possible? to catch everything BUT some specific exceptions?

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could do the following:

```py
try:
    do_stuff()
except (SyntaxError, <any other exception>):
    raise  # simply raises the catched exception
except Exception:
    print "yes, it's catching EVERYTHING"
```

In addition, unless it is really what is wanted, **`except` should never be used without exception specification since it will also catch `KeyboardInterrupt` and `GeneratorExit`**. `Exception` should be specified at least; see the [builtin exception hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy).

---

Note that, as @tobias_k stated in its below comment, the `SyntaxError` is detected before actually running the script, so it should not be needed to catch it.

For the challenge I looked for a way to actually catch a `SyntaxError` and the only case I found is the following (but there are other cases, see @brunodesthuilliers's comment):

```py
try:
    eval(input('please enter some Python code: '))
except SyntaxError:
    print('oh yeah!')
```

```
$ python syntax_error.py
please enter some Python code: /
oh yeah!
```

My conclusion is that if you need to catch `SyntaxError`, this means your codebase does some stuffs even uglier than what you showed us... I wish you a lot of courage ;)

Comment: I think the `SyntaxError` is not even needed, as those should be detected before running the program, but otherwise, e.g. for special treatment of `NameError`, fine.

Comment: @tobias_k I finally found a way to catch a `SyntaxError`, see the edited answer ;)

Comment: @Tryph : other candidates for a SyntaxError (py2, I leave it to you to check the py3 changes): `exec`, `execfile`, `compile`, `ast.literal_eval`, `ast.parse` etc...

Comment: @Tryph oh and yes: you should definitly put the "except should never be used without exception specification" in bold (and even in blod caps as far as I'm concerned). I almost downvoted your post before seeing this part. FWIW, you should edit your example to actually NOT use a bare except ;-)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers acknowledged

Comment: It is obvious to me that except: should not be used like in the question. It is also stated in the question. I don't really understand why the extensive re-discussion on the matter. Thanks for the great answer!

Comment: @Gulzar Other SO users could potentially have the same wondering. Even if **you** clearly stated that your are aware about this problem, it is a good thing to explain why it is bad because it could prevent bad practices for others than you.